# NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() versus DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable

```
    // Summary:
    //     Gets a value that indicates whether the network is available.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if there is at least one network interface available; otherwise, false.
    public static bool IsNetworkAvailable { get; }
```

NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()

```
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates whether any network connection is available.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if a network connection is available; otherwise, false.
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static bool GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

**Are these identical?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Microsoft wants you to use `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202859%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

`NetworkInterface` is in `System.Net` where as `DeviceNetworkInformation` is in `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation`.

The `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable` might map to `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` internally, but you should always use `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable` because it's made for the phone (and have a cleaner API).

And as pointed out by Matthieu, `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable` is apparently new in 7.1 (Mango).

Comment: Is it new with SDK 7.1? And more reliable that the NetworkInterface method?

Comment: I think it's new since the OS listed as supported is only 7.1